# Concurrent processing of messages with strict order 

Tags: java, concurrency, priority-queue

Within my JavaEE web application, I need to process incoming messages strictly in the order of arrival. I assume that my webapp container (Tomcat 6) retains the order of messages as they arrive at the http port.

What causes headaches to me, is the way I am internally processing these messages. For improved workload, I append the processing of each message to a ThreadPool as many things need to be done here e.g. XML parsing, sometimes enrichment of data using external web services. After processing is finished, I push the java representation of the message into a complex stream processing engine [esper.codehaus.org](http://esper.codehaus.org), which is threadsafe. Here, different patterns are checked where the entrance order is the highest requirement e.g threshold of a phenomenon exceeds.

I had the idea of inserting every processed message into a PriorityQueue with a priority ID they received at time of arrival (in my Servlet, where it is incremented for each message). The problem is the following:

The thread which is polling the elements from the queue (lowest ID is the head of the queue) for inserting it into esper could skip an ID as it does not check for missing items. I guess an illustration works out better:

[image]

For steps (1) to (4) everything works as intended. But at step (5) the QueuePoller retrieves element 6 and not element 4 (which is later inserted at step (6)). This results in the message order: 2; 3; 6; 4.

What I tried to do was to alter the implementation of polling the queue's head to follow the strict order of IDs. Meaning, if the next ID's element is not yet inserted into the queue, wait at a barrier until its there. This seemed to work for the first 10 minutes but then hanged, probably due to an element that never got inserted into the queue.

Anyone out there having a similar problem in the past and has some hint for me?

Comment: You might be better creating the queue items as soon as they arrive at your server then only allow them to be taken from the queue in order and once processing of them is complete.

Comment: What I don't understand is, if the order of elements in the output queue has to match the order in the input queue, what good is processing them out-of-order? That is, why do 6 before 4 if QueuePoller needs to have 4 before 6?

Comment: i thought about that two, but I guess it would lead to similar results. Assuming, I would use a flag which indicates that processing is finished, same problems could arise if something went wrong in the processing (server timeout, etc. which is imho also the problem why the element is not inserted). Thus, the indicator flag would never be set to true.

Comment: @aib: benefit from multi-core CPU and hardware usage if processing of messages (XML parsing, enrichment using web services) is costly. I did some stress tests on my application with Single-Thread-Solution and it showed less performance.

Comment: @matthes you polling solution might work, if you add polling timeout: if queue doesn't contain N ordered items after M milliseconds, take first chunk of ordered items and process them (maybe, chunk will contain just one item in the limit case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Disruptor](http://code.google.com/p/disruptor/) -- a high performance queue with strict order (first enter -- first served)

Comment: Damn, I was about to say that :-)

Comment: it seems that OP situation is that items are incoming into processing thread out-of-order and he needs to process them in order given by item's key. how will disruptor solve this?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will definitely check that out and report back, if it solved my problems. After a quick read it still does not seem to solve the waiting for missing elements - or I did not read enough.

Comment: The thing is disruptor splits two actions:  
1) When the "producer" thread "claims" a number it basically reserves it.  

2) When the "producer" thread has put its data into the queue, it commits and allows "consumers" to process it.  
  
Disruptor guarantees that messages would be processed in the order of claims. That means, if some "producer" has reserved #5, then consumer would wait untill it is ready even if there is already #6 in the queue.

Comment: ok, that seems like the thing I am looking for. I'll give it a try and report back! thanks

Comment: this is really great. guys, check out disruptor! it solved all my problems with less than 100 lines of code. Took me a while until I got the point that its not storing objects but just IDs as a key for the actual objects. this makes it lightning fast.

I compared it to a self-written container with timeouts as suggested by aib and Victor. Mine was way slower as it worked with mutliple barriers.

Answer (score 1):

You could instantly add a placeholder for incoming requests to your processing queue. The placeholder is preprocessed in the background by a thread pool but main processing waits for the preprocessing to be complete. The construct I have in mind is a [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

Answer (score 0):

The class library provides a flexible thread pool implementation along with some useful predefined configurations. You can create a thread pool by calling one of the static factory methods in Executors:

For your needs I think Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() is best. A single-threaded executor creates a single worker thread to process tasks, replacing it if it dies unexpectedly. Tasks are guaranteed to be processed sequentially according to the order imposed by the task queue (FIFO, LIFO, priority order).

Comment: That satisfies the ordering constraint indeed, however at the cost of performance.

Comment: Yup, as mentioned in above comments, this is the last solution I will realize, if everything else won't work. Processing of messages can be very costly in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

As evidenced by your problem and the need for a diagram (+1 for that, by the way) a priority queue is not a good construct for what you want. This is because a queue is perfectly happy to serve you an available 6 rather than to wait for an unavailable 4.

I think it's time to roll your own synchronized container.

Comment: Shouldn't be much more than abusing a priority queue :D